# How to find $\zeta(0)=\frac{-1}{2}$ by definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I would like to know how we can find the following result:

$$\zeta(0)=-\frac12$$

Is there a way, using the definition, $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^{-s}$$

to find this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider the integral
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{xt^{x-1}}{e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{xt^{x-1}}{1+e^{-t}}e^{-t}\;\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-kt}\;\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}k^{-x}\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\;\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x\eta(x)\Gamma(x)\\
&=(1-2^{1-x})\zeta(x)\Gamma(x+1)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Integrate by parts to get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^\infty\frac{xt^{x-1}}{e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^xe^t}{(e^t+1)^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(u+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Sending $x$ to $0$ in $(1)$ and combining with $(2)$, we get $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This was a bit hard to understand because you jumped some "trivial" steps, not so trivial to me =). I need to understand the part after `Integrate by parts to get` and then I'll embrace your answer. At the end I realized I'm more interested in the result, not find the result by definition and you did well. Thx.

Comment: @GarouDan: Let $u=\frac{1}{e^t+1}$ and $\mathrm{d}v=xt^{x-1}\;\mathrm{d}t$, then $v=t^x$ and $\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{e^t\;\mathrm{d}t}{(e^t+1)^2}$. [Integration by Parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) then says that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{e^t+1}xt^{x-1}\;\mathrm{d}t=\left.\frac{t^x}{e^t+1}\right|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty t^x\frac{e^t\;\mathrm{d}t}{(e^t+1)^2}
$$

Comment: @GarouDan: When $x>0$, $\frac{t^x}{e^t+1}=0$ at both $t=0$ and $t=\infty$. Thus, when taking $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}$ of both sides, the limit term (on the left of the sum) vanishes. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{e^t+1}xt^{x-1}\;\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^t\;\mathrm{d}t}{(e^t+1)^2}\\
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{(s+1)^2}
\end{align}
$$
where $s=e^t$.

Comment: Thx a lot @robjohn, this clarified everything. Nice answer^^

Comment: @robjohn, the second part of your integral if x=0 then the integral is zero at that point (including zero )unless is (0 , infinity) and so the answer should be zero

Comment: @user12878: are you claiming that $$ \lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^\infty\frac{xt^{x-1}}{e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t $$ is $0$? If so, note that as $x\to0^+$, $$ x\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}}{e^t+1}\mathrm{d}t $$ is of the form $0\cdot\infty$, so we cannot simply plug in $x=0$.

Answer (score 13):

The "defining sum" converges only for $\Re s > 1$. One can however use the related formula

$$\zeta(s)=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (k+1)^{-s}$$

for $s=0$. This complicated sum can be derived by applying the [Euler transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersSeriesTransformation.html) to the series for [Dirichlet $\eta$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html), the alternating version of Riemann's function.

Comment: Why can we consider $\eta(0)=1-1+1-1+1....=\frac{1}{2}$ in this case?

Comment: You do what I indicated above: since the usual series for Dirichlet $\eta$ converges only for $\Re s > 0$, performing the Euler transformation is what's needed to have an analytic continuation. The other possibility is to do analytic continuation via [Abel summation](http://eom.springer.de/a/a010170.htm). See [this article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) as well.

Comment: It is important always to keep uniqueness with respect to the single terms in the series, so if you want to derive a result for $\small \eta(0) $ you should write this as $\small \eta(0) = \lim_{s->0} \eta(s) = 1^{-s} - 2^{-s} + 3^{-s} - \ldots + \ldots $ so each of your ones above is uniquely identified. Only then you may operate algebraically until you have a form (or formula) which allows to read off the final value by neglecting residuals, which vanish as *s* goes to zero. I think the derivation for the $\small \eta(0) $ was given in the wikipedia?

Comment: Nice use of the Euler transformation (one of my favorite tools). (+1)