# How to prove that $u(X)\leqslant\max_{x\in\partial\Omega}u(X),\forall X\in\Omega$.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$,$u(X)\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$,if
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i^2}(X)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_i(X)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(X)\geqslant0,\forall X\in\Omega,$$
Where $b_i(X)(i=1,2,\cdots,n)$ is a continuous function.prove that
$$u(X)\leqslant\max_{x\in\partial\Omega}u(X),\forall X\in\Omega.$$
I think this problem means that the maximum value of $u(X)$ is obtained at the boundary, but I don't know how to start.Please help me,thank you!

Comment: Assume, by contradiction, that the max over $\Omega$ is achieved in the interior. What would the signs of the first and second partials be at that point?

Comment: @GReyes Thank you.To be honest, I don't know what this symbol is. This problem is an exercise in our textbook, which has bothered me for a long time.

Comment: What symbol are you referring to?

Comment: @GReyes It's the symbol you said...