# Is it possible to sum the divergent series with prime coefficients?

Tags: prime-numbers, divergent-series, regularization

This is a follow-up of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84642/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-value-to-the-sum-of-primes) question.

It is known that the divergent series $$ P := \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n \qquad \text{where } p_n \text{ is the $n$th prime} $$ cannot be summed by means of (prime) zeta function [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization). (The result was originally due to Landau and Walfisz, see [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03014596) paper. Froberg later showed it as [well](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01933420).)

However, there are loads of other summation methods. I am wondering whether any of the following summation methods can sum the divergent series of primes. For example:

1. Analytic continuation of power series: Does $\lim_{x \to 1^{-} } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_{n} x^{n} $ exist?
2. Lindelöf summation: Does $\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n n^{-nx} $ exist?
3. Analytic continuation of Dirichlet series: Does $\lim_{s \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{p_n}{n^s} $ exist?

Do any of these methods or another summation [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) for assigning a number to the sum of primes work? If so, please also indicate what the closed form of the corresponding function (for which the limit exists) is.

Answer (score 3):

As written the answer to all three is no, since

$$
\begin{align}
1.& \quad \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n x^n \geq \lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^{m} p_n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{m} p_n \text{ for all fixed $m$,} \\
2.& \quad \lim_{x \to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n n^{-nx} \geq \lim_{x \to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^m p_n n^{-nx} = \sum_{n=1}^{m} p_n \text{ for all fixed $m$, and} \\
3.& \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{p_n}{n^s} \text{ diverges for $s \leq 2$.}
\end{align}
$$

You could consider the last one only a technicality, since it may still be possible to find an analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series for $s \neq 2$, where it appears to have a pole of order $2$.  I'm not really familiar enough with these things to say.

Comment: $\sum \frac{p_n}{n^s}$ diverges for $\operatorname{Re} s \leqslant 2$ even. I have no idea whether that has an analytic continuation to $0$ either.

Comment: Whoops, right, thanks for the correction :)