# 1+2+3+4+... = -1/12

Tags: riemann-zeta

Consider the zeta function $\zeta(s)= \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$.

It is established that $ \zeta(-1) = -\frac{1}{12}$.

[Reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) (Equation 90)

Then we have $ \zeta(-1) =  \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{-1}}= 1+2+3+4 + ... = -\frac{1}{12}$.

But of course this series is divergent. So what is the problem here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39802/264

Comment: Thank you Zev! I tried to search but nothing came up. My question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

[Power Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) are only valid inside a [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence). For example, the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

$$1 + z^2 + z^4 + z^6 + \cdots \equiv \frac{1}{1-z^2}$$

for all $|z| < 1$. The identity does not hold for $|z| > 1$, and the identity may or may not hold when $|z|=1$. You need to read about [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: But the series here is not a power series at all...

Comment: @HenningMakholm It can be realised as the evaluation of a power series outside of its radius of convergence. Just like we have

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots \equiv \frac{1}{1-z}$$

for all $|z|<1$, and then we evaluate at $z=2$ to get the "answer"

$$1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @FlybyNight that's great for the power series $1+z+z^2+...$ but $\sum \frac{1}{n^s}$ is not a power series. It doesn't have a radius of convergence in the usual sense.

Comment: @FlybyNight; outside the radius of convergence doesn't mean anything, but for non-converging sums to infinity with finite answers, yours is $1+2^\infty$.