# Is every sum to something a limit of the sum?

Tags: limits, functions, summation

#### Old title:

Is it always true that a sum to some $m$ equals the limit of that sum to some $x$ such that $x$ tends to $m$?
$\ $

This may seem a stupid question, but I'm placing it because although it seems obviously true, it may not be so in some edge cases. After all, all true statements in mathematics are obvious (or at least analytic and/or tautological propositions).

Also, sorry for the long question title, but I didn't know how to phrase it without using "this".

$$
\forall f,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\},\ \forall m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0; \ \infty\},\ \forall x \in D_f, \sum_n^mf(x)=\lim_{x\to m}\sum_{n}^{x}f(x)
$$

Notice that often, $x = n$, they can be the very same variable. So, is the above true (under any circumstances, except wrongness, of course)?

**Added:** Note: I prefer not to state much about $x$ because even being an upper limit of a sum, it may be non-integer by analytic extension (I don't know if this is the correct name, but I think you get the idea) of the operation, in the limit, as $x$ approaches $m$, it may be a fractional number, perhaps requiring you to (if such is the function) do a half and then to do two thirds of a derivative, and add that to the previous complete derivatives, studying how the partial sums approach the final value.

## Examples

In the following examples the stated above applies.

### Where $x=n$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(9\times 10^{-n}\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{x}\left(9\times 10^{-n}\right)=10
$$

### Where $x\not=n$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^5 3=\lim_{x\to 5}\sum_{n=0}^{x}3=5\times 3=15
$$

Thank you in advance.

## Very Late Relevant Edit

I have found doubtful cases and reminded of this question, such as the one shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712448/recursive-square-root-problem/712450#answer-712450).

It seems quite obvious from evaluating partial sums that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n2^n=\infty
$$

however:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty2^n=2^0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^n=1+2\sum_{i=0}^\infty2^n
\iff\\
\iff-\sum_{i=0}^\infty2^n=1\iff\sum_{i=0}^\infty2^n=-1\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n2^n
$$

Which seems to **answer "no"** to my question. Unless I'm missing something. Am I? Is this logic correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum_n^x$ when $x$ is not an integer? And if $D_f$ only consists of integers, it's still not clear what you mean by the limit on the right hand side.

Comment: @mrf, thanks for the warning, I hadn't noticed it yet, see the updated post.

Comment: The *definition* seems fine, but (in very late edit) the *manipulation* using the symbol $\infty$ does not.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, what do you mean by *manipulation* of $\infty$? I didn't do any "tricks" with it. And by *definition*, you mean the definition of what exactly? Is what I added in the edit invalid?

Comment: On the next to last displayed line, the "taking out" a common factor of $2$ is slightly problematic, and the **subtraction** that leads to the beginning of the next line is definitely problematic.

Comment: Ah, now I see. If the sum was really $\infty$, it could be a problem to do $\infty-\infty$ as that is outside $\mathbb R$, so the validity of the subtraction is questionable. But about another sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n=-\frac1{12}$, the result is actually used in Physics, so it seems all this turns out fine.

Comment: @GinKin, how so? The first partial sum would be $9\times10^{-0}=9>1$

Comment: @JMCF125 oh yeah, didn't notice we start from $n=0$. Sorry.

Comment: @GinKin, no problem, sometimes I make that kind of mistakes as well, both in questions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $\sum_n^m f(x) = \sum_{x=n}^m f(x)$, then the formula you wrote is true. It is true for $m = \infty$ just by the definition of the infinite series, and for finite $m$ due to the fact that $\lim_{k}x_k = m$ for the integer sequence of $x_k$ if and only if $x_k = m$ for all $k$ big enough.

Comment: What if it is a sum of fixed values ($x\not = n$, thus my definition to cover this case)?

Comment: @JMCF125: can you provide an example, please?

Comment: Any case where $x$ is fixed and $n$ is variable.