# Simple Analogy to explain $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -1/12$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, riemann-zeta, popular-math

I'm looking for a simplified analogy to explain why the following formula does not actually mean what it seems to mean:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}$

I get this question all the time from high school students, probably because it was popularized by Numberphile on Youtube. (See video [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiznoqiv_zeAhWq8YMKHRTjC0wQyCkwAHoECAUQBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dw-I6XTVZXww&usg=AOvVaw36dQOJOrJEiXbEFx_HQhc5) and see associated post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086035/intuition-behind-zeta-1-frac-112))

Since the concept of power series expansion is tough for a lot of high school students to get (let alone the zeta function or analytic continuation), I'd like to give them some accessible way to understand how that equal sign isn't really doing what we normally think it is.

I am partially indebted to the answer of user3002473 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100668/using-the-rules-that-prove-the-sum-of-all-natural-numbers-is-frac112-ho?rq=1).

Please let me know if my understanding of the problem is correct and if my analogy makes sense and is apt:

- My understanding of the problem:

The zeta function exists everywhere in the complex plane, but its power series representation is valid **only on a portion** of the plane.

The equation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}$ is therefore the result of equating the "analytic continuation of the function" at a point outside the power series representation domain with the numerical value of the power series computed at that point.

In other words, each side of the equal sign is a valid representation of the zeta function, but neither representation is actually trying to communicate the numerical value of the function at that point.

- My analogy:

Consider a non-vertical line in the plane with slope, $2$, and y-intercept, $3$.  We can describe this line as a function between two sets of numbers, $f:X\rightarrow Y$

Clearly, we can see that the graph is one visual representation of the function, but we can also represent it as an equation in slope-intercept form: $f(x) = 2x+3$

Now, suppose I wanted to represent this line as a function with $x$ in the denominator.  I could do that like this:

$g(x) = \frac{2x^2+3x}{x}$

This is clearly a valid representation of my linear function, but it breaks down at the point $x=0$, like so:

$g(0) = \frac{2\times 0^2+3\times 0}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$

As we all know, $\frac{0}{0}$ is "undefined".

Key point:  The original function exists at $x=0$, but the *specific representation* $g(x)$ fails at that point.

Now, I could say, "We all know that $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined.  But **for this function**, we have enough information to 'define' it."

That is, we know that in the original function, the input $x=0$ is associated uniquely with the output $3$.

So, since $g(x)$ is a representation of our function, we could (strongly waving our hands) say that the output $g(0) = 3$

But then, we've just "proved":  $3 = \frac{0}{0}$

No, not really.  All we did was take equate two different representations, each valid over different domains, and equate them at a point they don't have in common.

Is this a reasonably accurate analogy to the trouble with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}$ ?

Comment: this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuIIjLr6vUA) is enough apt for your students? Your argumentation is *similar*, Im not sure how well this analogy can be, but it seems fine for a first approximation to the expression

Comment: "each side of the equal sign is a valid representation of the zeta function, but neither representation is actually trying to communicate the numerical value of the function at that point." I'm no expert, but I think the Riemann zeta function is *defined as* the analytic continuation of $\sum n^{-s}$, and its value at $s=-1$ is exactly $-1/12$. So, the left-hand side $\sum n$ is *not* a value of the Riemann zeta function, but the right-hand side *is*.

Comment: Trying to evaluate power series expansion outside of it's ***radius of convergence***.

Answer (score 1):

You can do *all kinds* of things like that, by plugging in numbers to a series outside its radius of convergence. You can take the Taylor series for 1/(1-x) & plug -1 in & 'prove' that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k=1/2 $$ (!) It all just emphasises the importance of keeping track of *convergence*, really.

The particular example you cite is a result of the *analytic continuation* of the *Riemann zeta function* beyond the domain on which its representation as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1\over{k^z}}$$ is valid. When one exhibits a pathological case such as the one you cite at the beginning of the question, one is just taking a result produced by a new *recipe* & projecting it back by sheer *force* onto the old, which no-one *ever did* say (at least no-one who understands the matter aright) was valid in the domain inwhich the new one has produced *its* result. And yet there is a *continuity* between the new & old recipes: they *splice together* seamlessly.

Convergence & analytic continuation are indeed *profound matters* ... and yet ultimately all you are doing is *counting*!

Comment: But that _particular_ result you cite: _Srinivasa Ramanujan_ was rather fond of that particular _paradox_ ... and if it's alright for _him_ then it's alright for _me_!

Comment: And other wishful stories for grown ups.

Comment: Yes, keeping track of convergence and also what the symbols "+" and "=" actually mean!  The big problem I have with the Numberphile video is that it sort of hand-waves by introducing Cesaro Mean Convergence, so I get a bunch of students who end up confident that you can just shift around numbers any way you like in infinite series and treat the answers like real numbers.  They're so amazed by the counter-intuitive result that it becomes more difficult to get them to stop and think about whether it makes sense, what it actually means, and what the subtleties are in getting to that result.

Comment: @mathreadler -- do you think the story of Ramanujan being particularly fascinated by that result is one of those 'stage-managed' fairytales? Like the guy who had national security round at his house coz he caluculated the strength of a nuclear bomb from photographs of the shock? It might well be - I doubt that Ramanujan particularly cared about a trivium like that.

Comment: @Cassius12 -- I'm not fully following your comment in all its particular detail ... but I get the gist of it, and I could think of similar figures of my own. And what you said about keeping track of the _meaning_ of "+" & "=" ... I can imagine how that need could come-about when you get _seriously_ deep into it; although I have never really gotten quite so deep _myself_ that I have felt called to examine the meaning of those particular symbols! ¶ And I have never seen the _Numberphile_ video.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey : He died very young. Makes it bit easier to stage manage all kinds of things, doesn't it?

Comment: It does ... it does. The 'taxicab-number' scene at his hospital bed, perhaps. And his wife refused to permit the publication of certain of his papers for the entire span of the rest her life (which was _long_) ... perhaps because she felt that Professor Hardy & Co had just _burnt him out_? But who can say what the rights of it are _ultimately_ ... we don't _know_ that a 'meteoric career' was contrary to his own will in the matter, or the consequence of a deluded will. Life _is_ tragic & short.