# Is "shift & add" technique valid for infinite sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The "shift & add" technique is an excellent trick to get standard formulas for summation of various finite sequences. e.g.

(Newbie here, couldn't get the aligning proper, so stuck to special case $n=5$)
$$
\begin{aligned}
1-2+3-4+5&=S\\
1-2+3-4&=S-5
\end{aligned}
$$
And, we could add up & get the results/formula accordingly. ($\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}k=\frac{1}{2}$)

But, is this trick suitable or correct when dealing with infinite sequences? e.g.
$$
\begin{aligned}
1-2+3-4+5-\cdots&=S\\
1-2+3-4+\cdots&=S
\end{aligned}
$$
The professor then adds up!? (isn't the result off by infinity?!) If this is correct, the *source* link result is quite astounding indeed, what more mathematical implications does it have?

**Source** - [ASTOUNDING: $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + \cdots = -{\frac{1}{12}}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39802/ (and a dozen more recent questions — starting from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/632985/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41938/, maybe)

Comment: ...and perhaps [Infinity = -1 paradox](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/37327) is quite relevant

Comment: (Now I'm tempted to vote to close as a duplicate — but not sure of which question...)

Comment: How can a finite sum of integers be equal to $\frac12$?

Comment: @TonyK I am sorry, it should be infinity, editing accordingly. Also, Grigory, I too see now that it's a duplicate. Plenty of comments regarding my other related question too on these questions you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Flagged duplicate for the same. It's exactly the question I had in mind.