# About the series $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\ldots$ and $a_{1}+0+a_{2}+0+a_{3}+0+\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $S=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+\ldots+a_{n}+\ldots$, is it true that $$S=a_{1}+0+a_{2}+0+a_{3}+0+\ldots+a_{n}+0+\ldots\ ?$$

I think the second series $S'_{n} \not =S_{n}$, so it is false. But I'm not sure about that because when $n$ becomes larger and larger, it seems to be the same.

Comment: The general terms are $a'_n = a_n + 0 = a_n$. So these series have the same general term thus there are equal.

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915710/proof-that-1-11-1-cdots-frac12-and-related-conclusion-that-zeta2/915714#comment1890383_915714) by user @JiK.

Comment: @Deuteu No, the general term is $a'_{2n-1}=a_n$ and $a'_{2n}=0$.

Comment: @Did OK. I didn't see it like this.

Answer (score 3):

If $S_n=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}{a_n}$ **converges** to $S$.

Let $b_n=a_1+0+a_2+0+\cdots$ upto $n$ terms. Then $$b_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}a_{\frac n2}& n \text{ is even} \\ a_{\frac{n+1}{2}} & n \text{ is odd} \end{array}\right.$$

Now observe that $b_{2n}\rightarrow S$ and $b_{2n+1}\rightarrow S$.

*Lemma*: Let $t_n$ be a sequence,  if $t_{2n}\rightarrow t$ and $t_{2n+1}\rightarrow t$, then $t_n \rightarrow t$.

Use the lemma to observe that $b_n\rightarrow S$.

But the question on whether the two sequences are equal can have different answers when we change perspective of equality. The terms are not equal, both converges to same limit etc.

If $S_n$ is **not convergent**, we can obtain bizarre results like $1+1+1+\cdots =1+(1+-1)+1+(1+-1)+\cdots=2+2+2+\cdots$.

Comment: I agree that it is completely obvious. But the point seems to be that the new series has twice as many terms, ie $a'_{2n-1}=a_n,a'_{2n}=0$. So you have to establish that you are free to group terms. If the original series was not absolutely convergent, nailing the proof down for a pedant requires a little work.

Comment: But $1+1+1+⋯=2+2+2+⋯$ is not "bizarre", it is obviously true, no? :-)

Comment: @Did actually the two series are 
divergent

Comment: @Leilan.Shaw No kidding. :-)