# Could $4+2+4+2+4+2+\cdots = -1 $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, interpolation, divergent-series

In physics classes, on this StackExchange and even in blogs the sum $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots = - \frac{1}{12} $ has been under the microscope.

- [Why does $1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12)
- [The Euler-Maclaurin formula, Bernoulli numbers, the zeta function, and real-variable analytic continuation](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/)

As a consequence of the trapezoid rule, the error to the Riemann sum is bounded by the second derivative.

$$ \int_0^N f(x) \; dx = \frac{1}{2}f(0) + f(1) + \dots + f(N-1) + \frac{1}{2}f(N) + O\,(N \| f \|_{\dot{C}^2} ) $$

Letting $f(x) = (1-x/N)_+$ we get $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1 = -\frac{1}{2} + \int_0^N 1 \, dx + O(1)$.

I am wondering what happen if we use the [Simpson rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule):

$$ \int_0^N f(x) \; dx = \frac{1}{3} \big( f(0) + 4f(1) + 2f(2) + \dots + 4f(N-1) + f(N)  \big) + O\,(N || f ||_{\dot{C}^4} ) $$

Now we plug in $f(x) = (1-x)_+$ and get

$$\frac{1}{3} (4 + 2 + 4 + 2 + \cdots )  =  -\frac{1}{3} + \int_0^N f(x) \; dx +  O(N^{-3}) $$

Is that still consistent with the other types of sums you get from Euler-Macularin type summation methods?

Comment: Numberphile
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww

Comment: oh what a great video!  i will show to my friends!

Comment: In your title, I understand what $4+2+4+2+4+2$ means. I also understand what $-1$ means on the right-hand side. The part I don't understand is "$+\cdots$". Could you please explain what this means?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful when claiming that infinite, divergent sums add to a real number. Strictly speaking, this makes no sense since you cannot manipulate indefinite sums the way you please. The video @Jonas12 posted is useful, but I would also recommend watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oazb7IWzbA to further comprehend the nature of this result.