# Problem involving Integers and Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Compute the following sums: 
a) 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n; 
b) 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2n-1;
c) 2 + 5 + 8 + ... + 3n-1 
d) a + (a+d) + (a+2d) + ... + (a+(n-1)d)

I have found that the sum of a) = -1/12. I have no idea how to find the rest, does anyone else have any idea? 
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Your answer to a) is wrong.

Comment: To answer you questions see See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Partial_sums

Answer (score 0):

These are all presumably finite sums, not infinite.  These are all sums of [arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).  The first should be $\frac 12n(n+1)$.  Presumably your answer of $-\frac 1{12}$ was found by Google search, I suggest you unlearn it.  It was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12)

Comment: why is it 1/2n(n+1)  that doesn't seem to make sense because this seems to result in, (1,3,6,10...)

Comment: Yes, and that is the sum of $1,2,3,\dots$ terms of the progression.  For example, $1+2+3=6$