# Why do we assign values to divergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Why do we assign values to divergent series?  For example, the series $1+2+3+4... = -1/12$.  I understand the proof for this, but I feel like it uses false math, and I recall reading that you can't do arithmetic/algebra with series that aren't absolutely convergent.  Obviously this series diverges, but why do we say it equals -1/12?

Thanks!

Comment: What's "the proof for this" you mention, @Ethan??

Comment: It definitely uses false math. I don't think many mathematicians literally treat this as an equality. In this case, for example, a mathematician might say $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$.

Comment: @DonAntonio You haven't seen the video that was going around a few months ago? This has been a big deal, and a really frustrating example of bad popular math.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, no I didn't though I heard of it. I just want to make sure what the OP's talking about.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas: it's not a duplicate; I'm just using that as an example.  Another example could be $1-1+1-1...  = 1/2$.

Comment: Series aren't infinite sums, they are sequences. And you can define several functions that will give a value to some of these sequences. The usual one is $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}\mapsto \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^nu_n$ but there are others such as $\left(u_n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}\mapsto \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\cfrac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^iu_j}{n}$. You just have to make sure it's a function: each sequence has at most one associated value.

Comment: Well, that's not a function @xavierm02, it's a partial function. :)

Comment: @Ethan, some of the links and answers provided in that question should be useful.

Comment: None of the answers here are good. Nor do they adequately answer the OP's question. There has to be two kinds of answers to the question. One kind is to show how the generalization should "naturally" arise. The other is to show a specific application of the divergent series having a certain value assigned to it being useful in that context.

Comment: @Ethan: I think "why do we say it equals -1/12" led to the duplicate marking. Your first question seemed to be asking, "What is the motivation for assigning values to divergent series?" But all other commentary indicates that you wanted to know, "Why do we assign the specific values we assign to particular divergent series?" Now that I re-read your question, I'm not sure which you were asking. Regardless of the intended question, the answers are in GH Hardy's book "Divergent Series"!

Comment: The question is not about "how" do we assign... but "why" do we assign *("Why do we assign values to divergent series?")*. I'm really surprised to see so many answers and comments here which focus the "how"... Well, to give one answer for the "why": it is for completion of the field of possible mathematical operations. One could similarly ask: "why do we assign a value to the squareroot of a negative number?" and answer: just to complete the operation of multiplication - for multiplication of a number with itself and for that operation's inverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motivation cited in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww&list=TL-W-CvIcl0OEhXRe1D5OEQS0XiWxH7xlq) involves applications to physics. I shall give an alternative reason.

In G.H. Hardy's book "Divergent Series", a classic on the topic, he gives (on pages 2 and 3) a derivation of the following famous result due to Euler: $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
That is a convergent series. The derivation given, due to Euler, uses divergent series! It is true that Euler had other derivations and also true that today we can prove the result using complex analysis without appealing to divergent series. But, just as we can prove results about real-valued functions by appealing to complex-valued functions, so too can we assign values to sequences associated to divergent series in a way that allows manipulations that recover the value of a convergent series. It can pay off to enter a so-called "imaginary world" if the math is made rigorous and there is a way back to whatever is thought of as "real".

Regarding "false math": We might be better off just saying there is an operation (that we shall not call "summation") that assigns values to particular sequences. Then all of these manipulations can be made rigorous in a way that leaves no doubt. It seems that by using the word "sum" in association to the values assigned to divergent series, we create confusion. I leave you with G.H. Hardy's very insightful take on the matter (pages 5-6). The transformations he refers to are divergent series assignments and manipulations of those assignments:

"The results of the formal calculations of [many nice formulae including the one given above] are correct wherever they can be checked: thus all the formulae [...] are correct. It is natural to suppose that the other formulae will prove to be correct, and our transformations justifiable, if they are interpreted appropriately. We should then be able to regard the transformations as shorthand representations of more complex processes justifiable by the ordinary canons of analysis. It is plain that a first step towards such an interpretation must be some definition, or definitions, of "sum" of an infinite series, more widely applicable than the classical definition of Cauchy.

This remark is trivial now: it does not occur to a modern mathematician that a collection of mathematical symbols should have a "meaning" until one has been assigned to it by definition. It was not a triviality even to the greatest mathematicians of the eighteenth century. They had not the habit of definition: it was not natural to them to say, in so many words, "by X *we mean* Y". There are reservations to be made, to which we shall return [...]; but it is broadly true to say that mathematicians before Cauchy asked not "How shall we *define* 1 - 1 + 1 - ...?" but "What *is* 1 - 1 + 1 - ...?" and that this habit of mind led them into unnecessary perplexities and controversies which were often really verbal."

Answer (score 0):

For the zeta function we have the followings:

first $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}, \quad
\text{if}\quad {\rm Re} s> 1,$$
and second (due to analytic continuation )
$$\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}.$$

So, if we "formally put" $s=-1$, we'll get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n =1+2+3+4+\dots = -\frac{1}{12}.$$

Comment: As far as I know, $\;\text{Re}(-1)<1\;$ , so the expression you use for the zeta function's isn't valid...What's your point here?

Comment: He wasn't asking about this particul'ar example, but the general question about divergent series being ascribed 'values.'

Comment: The point is that a naive person would try to substitute $\zeta(-1)$ the other way, @DonAntonio. The point isn't that there is an actual identity, but that this is one of the ways to interpret this nonsensical result.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12?lq=1

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks a lot. I was asking the poster. I know quite a few things about the zeta function, its analytic continuation and etc., but not that many about others' points.

Comment: @DonAntonio I figured you knew, but when you ask questions here, expect people to answer them.

Comment: Yes, @ThomasAndrews. Thanks...though I expected the one I asked directly would be the one answering...and still I can't be sure what was Mher's point, go figure.

Comment: So, technically, you weren't asking a question you wanted an answer to, you asked a question for pedagogical purposes? Why not just suggest a change, if you knew the answer to your question? If you think the answer can be improved, suggest an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

For how I understand the statement "$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}n=-\frac{1}{12}$" (which is technically false), comes from the fact that we have the Riemann zeta function which is defined for $s\in\mathbb{C}$ **with $\Re(s)>1$**:
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$$
Now this function admits an (unique, by the identity theorem) analytic continuation, which satisfies $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$.

To answer the more general question, it makes no sense to assign a value to a divergent series, since by using theorems which are valid for convergent series on divergent ones we can obtain basically any value we want (I've seen a proof of this fact, if I find it I will post it). For example we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n=1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(-1)^{2n}+(-1)^{2n+1}]=0$$
Etc.

Comment: He wasn't asking about this particular example, but the general question....

Comment: So if this is technically false, does that mean analytic continuation is false?

Comment: @Ethan No, the analytic continuation is correct, it's just that it equals the definition with the summation only where it is defined, i.e. for $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: So why exactly is it technically false, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Act 1: "does that mean analytic continuation is false?" – Act 2: "No, the analytic continuation is correct..." Act 3: "So why exactly is it technically false..." Hmmmm...

Comment: It seems to me that Daniel doesn't know what is meant by a "divergent series", this is something which has a great tradition in analysis.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Properties_of_summation_methods to see an overview of various methods to "sum" divergent series and desirable properties that summation methods are often demanded to satisfy, like linearity. Under the assumption that a summation method has various desirable properties, you can show for example that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n = 1 + a \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$$

so that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = 1/(1-a)$$

even if $a > 1$.