# Would it ever make sense to assign $1+2+3+4+5+\dots$ a value of $\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, divergent-series

I understand that the [Cesaro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) is a way of assigning values to divergent sums based on the limits of averages.

Are there other approaches to assigning values?

In the case of $1+2+3+4\dots$, there is no limit to the average.  So, if I am understanding right, Cesaro Summation does not assign a value for this sum.

Is there a well known principle that explains why certain values could not work as assigned values for a divergent sum?

---

Edit:  I made a mistake in my logic so my argument is invalid.  I am removing my argument which is flawed (I see no value in keeping it).  If someone can assign a value to this divergent sequence or explain why no value can be assigned, I will accept that answer.

Comment: [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: Unless you have some reason to assign the value of $1$ to the divergent series $1+1+1+1+\dots$, you've made an algebra error in progressing from the second to the third line (where you define $2x-1$).

Comment: (That being said, this kind of approach to divergent series is generally rife with contradictions and not very useful.)

Comment: Got it.  Thanks @Micah.  I get it now.  $2x -1$ should be $1+4+6+8 + \dots$.  Thanks very much.  That was the answer I was looking for.  :-)

Comment: @Solitary, fantastic link.  Thanks very much!

Comment: You did wrong on your $2x-1$

Comment: Isn't there something in wikipedia's "divergent series"?

Comment: @Gottfried, you are right.  The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) is an excellent article.  It answers my question:

Comment: There is a whole Wikipedia article devoted to this series: [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). It lists three summability methods that assign it a (generalized) sum of $-1/12$.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Looks like a great article.