# What's wrong with this "proof" that $\infty = -1$?

Tags: infinity, geometric-series

So I'm not great at math which is why I'm asking this.

Someone send me the next math:

Sum($1+2+4+8+16+$..)= infinity

Which I understand

S=sum($1+2+4+8+16+$..)

S=1+sum($2+4+8+16+$..)

So this came with the comment, first number shifted out of the sum.

S=1+2*sum(1+2+4+8+..)

Now I lost my mind, he got the second one out as well but starting at 1 again?

Folllw up of the math:

$S=1+2*S$

So S=-1 !

Infinity = -1

I saw a video about adding to infinity, but that included a negative number in order to get -1

**Literally copied and translated every comment in there:**

1+2+4+8+16+32+..= ?

Now you can say: infinite but you can also prove that it is -1!

Look that goes like this:

Som(1+2+4+8+16+..)= infinite, seems quite logical because the series goes on and on ..

But there is also:

S=som(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ..) # so

S=1+som(2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ..)  # first term out, nothing special, and so

S=1+2*som(1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ..) # factor 2 taken out of the sum, and so

S=1 + 2 * S # according to the original definition of the sum, and so

S=-1 !

In other words: infinite = -1!

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 2^n=\infty$, your operations are invalid.

Comment: $$\infty=\infty+\infty\implies \infty=0$$

Comment: The downvotes seem a little harsh here. This appears to be an honest question and there's a little bit of effort shown. I'm guessing it's a duplicate somehow though . . .

Comment: I mean: sure, it's grossly misinformed, but let's remedy that :)

Comment: @user2345215 As I said I'm not that good at maths. IF you could explain why my operations are invalid. Because the one sending it sends more look a like questions which normally are legit.

Comment: Perhaps you are wondering why $1+2 +2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots = -1$. This is a valid question. And if you rephrase it like that, it's going to get some attention, and some answers. For instance, it is true in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the reasoning $S=1+2S\implies S=-1$. This holds only for finite $S$ (cancelling infinities doesn't preserve the limiting behavior).

Comment: Would this mean the sum is correct, but the statement infinity = -1 is not? I'm sorry, not great at math + english isn't my native language.

Comment: @PrivateerGerrit Yes, the sum is $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how exactly would this work out, since I can't seem to get on -1 as answer.

P.S Also added the original "text", maybe some necessary information in there

Comment: @PrivateerGerrit The last line is false as I stated in my post. I won't discuss this further, it's been discussed a zillion times on this site, so search for it.

Answer (score 4):

This may be to your surprise. In certain settings, the statement

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots = -1$$
is true and the manipulation
$$S = 1 + 2S \quad\implies\quad S = -1$$
is actually legal! The catch is **the convergence of the series is not the ordinary one over real numbers**!

To understand this, we need to step back and ask what the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are.

One way to construct $\mathbb{R}$ is start from the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. On $\mathbb{Q}$, we have the ordinary absolute value $|x|$. Using this absolute value, we can turn $\mathbb{Q}$ into
a metric space by defining the usual Euclidean distance:

$$d(x,y) \stackrel{def}{=} |x-y|,\quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$$
When $\mathbb{Q}$ is endorsed with the Euclidean metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$, we can talk about [Cauchy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) over $\mathbb{Q}$.

> A sequence $(a_i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is Cauchy if for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find
>   an integer $N$ such that $d(a_i,a_j) < \epsilon$ whenever $i, j \ge N$.

We can setup equivalence relations among these Cauchy sequences:

> Two Cauchy sequences $(a_i)$, $(b_i)$ are equivalent if and only if $d(a_i,b_i) \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$.

We can define addition, multiplication and other operations on these equivalence classes of
Cauchy sequences over $\mathbb{Q}$. It turns out these collections of equivalence classes give you something behaves exactly like the familiar real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

In certain sense, we can construct $\mathbb{R}$ by filling the *holes* among elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the holes are measured with respect to the Euclidean metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$. For more details along this line, look up wiki's entry
on [Construction of real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences).

The important point is there are more than one way to assign "absolute value" to rational numbers. In particular, given any prime $p$ we can define something called [p-adic valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) for integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
and then extend it to rational numbers $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$:

$$v_p(n) = \begin{cases}
\max\{ v \in \mathbb{N} : p^v | n \},& \text{ if } n \ne 0\\
\infty,&\text{ if } n = 0
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
v_p\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = v_p(a) - v_p(b)
$$

Using this, we can define an alternate absolute value, the [p-adic norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_Norm) for the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$\mathbb{Q} \ni x \quad\mapsto\quad |x|_p = 
\begin{cases} 
p^{-v_p(x)},& \text{ if } x \ne 0\\
0,& \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases}$$

If you repeat the above procedure for $\mathbb{R}$, you can fill in the holes measured with respect to the p-adic norm $|x|_p$ and get something called the 
[p-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Similar to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a [complete metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space). You can talk about sequences, series, convergence and do all  sort of analysis over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For example, for any prime $p$, following geometric series converges
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k = 1 + p + p^2 + \cdots 
\quad\to\quad \frac{1}{1-p} \quad\text{ in }\; \mathbb{Q_p}$$
because $|p|_p = \frac{1}{p} < 1$.
In particular, when $p = 2$, we have
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots 
\quad\to\quad = \frac{1}{1-2} = -1 \quad\text{ in }\; \mathbb{Q_2}$$

The proof is exactly the same as what you will do over real numbers:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}\quad\text{ for }\; |x| < 1\;\text{ in }\;\mathbb{R}$$

In short,

- The sum is $-1$ when you are working with numbers in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.
- The sum is $\infty \not\in \mathbb{R}$ when you are working with numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.
- Over $\mathbb{Q}_2$, the manipulation
  $$S = 1 + 2S \quad\implies\quad S = -1$$
  is legal because the series $S$ converges absolutely. The same manipulation is illegal over $\mathbb{R}$ because the series $S$ diverges with respect to the Euclidean metric.
- Finally, $\infty \ne -1$ because $\mathbb{Q}_2 \ne \mathbb{R}$.

**Advice**

People like to throw out this sort of statements just to confuse you.
They are only mind boggling if one ignore the true meanings behind the symbols.

Comment: This is all nice and dandy, but somehow I doubt the OP will be able to understand anything. But it's for other people too, so +1.

Comment: @user2345215 I also have the concern the OP can't understand this. That's why I'm more verbose than usual. I hope the OP can at least catch the point: "there are some truth behind the sum S = -1".

Answer (score 4):

**Analytic Regularization**

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/632862) tries to explain why it is said that
$$
1+2+3+4+5+\dots=-\frac1{12}\tag{1}
$$
because
$$
\zeta(-1)=-\frac1{12}\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac1{1^s}+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\frac1{5^s}+\dots\tag{3}
$$
since plugging $s=-1$ into $(3)$ and formally applying $(2)$ gives $(1)$. However, $(3)$ does not converge for $\mathrm{Re}(s)\lt1$.

In that answer, an analytic function defined by a series is extended past where the series has meaning: a process called [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

---

**Application to the Question**

In a similar manner, we can take the series
$$
1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+\dots=\frac1{1-z}\tag{4}
$$
and plug in $z=2$ to get
$$
1+2+4+8+16+\dots=-1\tag{5}
$$
The proof of $(4)$ is exactly the proof given in the question:
$$
1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+\dots=1+z(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+\dots)\tag{6}
$$
Subtracting $z(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+\dots)$ from both sides of $(6)$ gives
$$
(1-z)(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+\dots)=1\tag{7}
$$
which leads to $(4)$. However, the series in $(4)$ does not converge for $|z|\ge1$.

We can see where the proof of $(4)$ breaks down for $|z|\ge1$ if we remove the hand-wavy dots ($\dots$). To be precise, equation $(7)$ *should* say
$$
(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k=1-z^n\tag{8}
$$
As $n\to\infty$, the right side of $(8)$ converges to $1$ only when $|z|\lt1$.

Thus, while $(5)$ appears formally true, it appears so only because we have extended the analytic function $\frac1{1-z}$ as a series past the point where $(4)$ has meaning.