# How to explain contradictory results from manipulation of infinite sums?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1\ldots$. Then $1 - S = S$ so $S = \frac{1}{2}$ Now suppose $T = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4\ldots$.  We can also write $T = 0 + 1 - 2 + 3 - 4\ldots$. Adding the two we get $2T = (1+0)+(-2+1)+(3-2)+(-4+3)\ldots$ or $2T = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1\ldots$, so $T = \frac{1}{4}$. Now let $P=1+2+3+4+5\ldots$. It can be easily seen that $P-T = 4P$ or $P=-\frac{T}{3} =-\frac{1}{12}$ so we have $P = -\frac{1}{12}$ How it is possible that $1 + 2 + 3 + 4\ldots=-\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: Here's some info http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39802/115823

Comment: You cannot actually define $S$ because it doesn't even converge.

Comment: @Vim One can define *anything*; the difficult part is making a consistent definition. :)  There are certain ways of assigning values to "classically" divergent series, such as [Cesàro summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).

Comment: @anorton However I don't see the point in doing this o(╯$\nabla$╰)o

Answer (score 3):

This comes down to a fundamental misconception of an infinite series. The series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i$ diverges, so the notation $1-S = S$ doesn't make any sense. Similarly for the other claims. It turns out infinity is weird, and so adding together infinitely many numbers is weird too.

Further, from our common understanding of the convergence of an infinite series, $\sum_{i=i}^\infty i$ diverges, as in the sequence of partial sums $\{ \sum_{i=1}^k i\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ has infinite limit.