# What does the false infinite sum of a series mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fake-proofs

For any geometric series with |$r$| < 1 , I know that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{∞} ar^{k-1} =\frac{a}{1-r}$$

But if |$r$| > 1 and you try to use the formula, you'll get a weird answer. For instance:

$$4+8+16+32+64+128+... =\sum_{k=1}^{∞} (4)2^{k-1}= \frac{4}{1-2} = -4$$

That answer obviously doesn't make sense; the series diverges. So what does -4 mean? Where did it come from, and how is it related to the series? It must be significant somehow.

Comment: Just a quick comment: The value $-4$ may somewhat be related to analytic continuation of the complex function $1/(1-z)$, just as a famous "formula" $1+1/2+1/3+\cdots=-1/12$, but I'm not sure at all. Someone (or I?) will discuss about it in answer when he/she gets convinced.

Comment: Sorry for typos...I mean $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$. This is a consequence of analytic continuation of a Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Maybe you want to read this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112

Comment: Your summation can also be derived with some (precarious) algebra. What is $x$? $$\begin{align*}x&=4+8+16+32+64+\cdots \\
(1/4)x&=1+2+4+8+16+\cdots \\ (1/4)x&=1+2+x \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the formula for a *finite* geometric series first. If $a$ is the first term, $r$ is the common ratio, and $n$ is the number of terms, then your sum is equal to $a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$. Now, if $|r|<1$, we can see that as $n$ goes to infinity the $r^n$ term disappears, leaving the familiar formula of $a\frac{1}{1-r}$. So, the infinite geometric series sum formula makes the assumption that $|r|<1$.

With the finite geometric series sum formula, we can rewrite as follows:

$$a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

$$=a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

$$=\frac{a}{r-1}r^n - \frac{a}{r-1}$$

Remember, an infinite sum is just the limit as $n\to\infty$ of a finite sum. 
Now, we know that the infinite sum assumes that $r^n$ goes to 0. If we assume that the first term goes to 0 even though it doesn't, we end up with the second term of that last line: $$\frac{-a}{r-1}$$

If you look at the terms individually, you can see that as $n\to\infty$ the first term goes to infinity. In a sense, you can think of that number you get as "ignoring infinity's contribution" to the sum (though this idea is very informal). It's what the sum *would have been* if the first term disappeared like it does when $|r|\lt1$.

Answer (score 5):

For a truncated series, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^Kar^{k-1}=a\frac{1-r^K}{1-r} \tag 1$$

For $a=4$ and $r=2$, use of $(1)$ reveals

$$\sum_{k=1}^K4\left(2\right)^{k-1}=4\frac{1-2^K}{1-2}=2^{K+2}-4$$

The $-4$ appears as the "convergent component" of the divergent series (as $K\to \infty$).

Comment: This is a answer that tells everything to need for tethernova to think (400+?)

Comment: @Moti I have no idea what you mean.  Help me understand. And why did you single out this answer when others posted similar ones??

Comment: Because it clearly explains your false interpretation of the sum equation that you used which is an estimation if r is small. IT IS NOT INTENDED TO BE USED WITH LARGE r - as result you get an unexplained erroneous answer.

Comment: @Moti Tethernova knows that - they want to know if it has any meaning.

Comment: @Moti Why the offensive tone?  Please refrain.  Or do we need a moderator here?  And I have not posted a "false interpretation of the sum equation."  And it is valid for all $K$ and for all $r$ - even complex valued $r$.  This is merely a truncated sum and clearly shows the source of the $-4$ as the "convergent" component of the divergent series.  Do you understand now?

Comment: I was not referring to you, as you may see from my first comment - so what exactly you talk about? @Deusovi from the way he presented the question it is not clear that he asks about the meaning. A great discussion of related issues may be found in the zeta function...

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Answer (score -6):

This is a way
of assigning meaning
to an otherwise divergent sum.

Look up "divergent series."

The subject is large.

Answer (score -6):

This is an estimation! If you will look how this estimation is derived you will see immediately that the sum goes to infinity because of $r^n$ in the sum