# what is the value of $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(-1)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, divergent-series

We've been told over and over [$\boxed{\zeta(-1) = 1 + 2 +3 + 4 + \dots =  - \frac{1}{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112?noredirect=1&lq=1) can be do the same over number fields?

What should be the reasonable value for the [zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function) $F = \mathbb{Q}(i) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$:

$$ \zeta_F(-1) = \sum_{ m + in \in \mathbb{Z}[i]} \sqrt{m^2 + n^2} = 0 + 4 \Big( 1 + \sqrt{2} + 2\sqrt{3} + 2 + 2\sqrt{5} +\dots \Big)$$

Comment: What you have been told over and over is wrong.

Comment: What we're told over and over is that the sum is $\frac{-1}{12}$, not $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Comment: We know the partial sums of the infinite series don't converge, rather the infinite series defines a function that can be analytically continued and then evaluated at $-1$ and meanwhile the series evaluated at $-1$ formally looks like a given divergent series. I'd just like to pre-emptively avoid an argument where we rehash all that, as we are wont to do.

Comment: Anyway, $\zeta_{\Bbb Q[i]}(s)=\zeta(s)\beta(s)$ where $\beta$ is the [Dirichlet $\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). Wikipedia says $\beta$ vanishes at odd negative integers, which would make this $0$.

Comment: $\zeta(-1)\ne 1+2+3+4+\ldots + n + \ldots$, that's the biggest problem. It has a finite value, but that value is not related to the given series, neither is the series you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dedekind zeta function](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dedekind-zeta-function/) $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}$ factors as a product between the usual $\zeta$ function and a Dirichlet $L$-function $L(s,\chi_4)$ associated with the Legendre symbol $\!\!\pmod{4}$. Given the reflection formula for the $\zeta$ function, it is enough to use the reflection formula for the previous $L$-function to find the zeta-regularization of your series. Why that number should be relevant, is another question.

Comment: It would be much more interesting to ask the same question for a real quadratic field