# What is wrong with this demonstration regarding the sum of all naturals?

Tags: summation, divergent-series, infinite-groups

If [this is correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39811/142244), then the [demonstration below](https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-explain-1+2+3+4+5+%E2%8B%AF+n-1-12-to-a-7-year-old) must have a fault, but I can't find it.

> Assuming $1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$ (1) is true.
>
> Adding $0$ on both sides: $0 + 1+2+3+\cdots = 0 -\frac{1}{12}$ (2)
>
> Subtracting (2) from (1),
>
> we get, $1+1+1+1+1+1+\cdots=0$ (3)
>
> Adding $0$ on both sides again,  $0+1+1+1+1+1+\cdots = 0 + 0$ (4)
>
> Now subtracting (4) from (3)
>
> we get, $1=0$, which is  a contradiction.
>
> Obviously our assumption that $1+2+3+4+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$ is wrong.

There is some error in the steps above, but I cannot find it. What is it?

Comment: $1+2+\cdots$ and $0+1+2+\cdots$ do not converge, so they are not real numbers, so you cannot use them in basic operations such as subtractions. Subtracting (2) from (1) you obtain $\infty-\infty$ on the left hand side, which is undefined (and definitely not defined as $1+1+\ldots$).

Comment: It is not actually true that $1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$ for the standard definition of infinite sums.  There are just some contexts in which you get useful results if you treat it as being true.

Comment: Did you read all of [the original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112), its context, the tags for the question, all the comments, the comments challenging the answer you link to, and all the other answers offered?

Comment: Essentially, https://twitter.com/ZachWeiner/status/625711339520954368

Answer (score 1):

The error is that
you assumed a result
that is false when using
standard definitions
of summation
and convergence.

The result
$1+2+3+\cdots 
= -\frac{1}{12}
$
is only true
when nonstandard methods
of summation are allowed.

This is like claiming that
$1+2+4+8+...
=-1
$
since
$\dfrac1{1-x}
=1+x+x^2+...
$
and substituting
$x=2$
to gives
$1+2+4+...
=\dfrac1{1-2}
=-1
$.