# Showing that $i^n=0$ when $i$ is the imaginary unit and $n$ is infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Let be the sum:
$$\begin{align}
s&= i+i^2+i^3+\cdots+i^n\\
 &= i-1-i+1+i-\cdots\\
 &=(1+i)(1-1+1-1+\cdots)
\end{align}$$
As Grandi's sum is equal to $1/2$, so: $s=\frac12(1+i)$.

But, $s$ is also a geometric series, so:
$s=\displaystyle\frac{(1-i^{(n+1)})}{(1-i)}$

So:
$$\frac12(1+i) = \frac{(1-i^{(n+1)})}{(1-i)}$$

Which means:
$$1-i^{(n+1)}=\frac{(1+i)(1-i)} 2=1$$

So $i^n=0$ when $n$ is infinite.

Comment: $1-1+1-1+ \ldots$ is a divergent series, and *not* equal to $1/2$. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059629/does-grandis-series-diverge-or-is-it-equal-to-frac12 and the linked threads.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What you wrote is everything except maths.

Comment: The sum Cesaro of Grandi's series is $1/2$

Comment: You can't mix Cesàro summation and methods for convergent series. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given series is divergent.

If you want to apply  [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Definition) you must proceed as follows
$$s_n=\sum _{k=1}^n i^k=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) \left(-1+i^n\right)$$
$$a_m=\sum _{n=1}^m s_n=-\frac{1}{2} i \left(i^m-(1+i) m-1\right)$$
and finally
$$S=\underset{m\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{a_m}{m}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}$$