# The sum of the series $\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt(N)}$

Tags: ramanujan-summation

Proving that the sum of $\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt(N)}= -\frac{1}{\sqrt(3)}$

Hi, I am trying to proving the sum above where $N$ is all the odd composites , any hint please ?

Comment: Do you **really** believe that the sum of a series of positive numbers can be negative?

Comment: Yes, we already know that $1+2+3+4+5+...= \frac{-1}{12}$, here the wikipedia page  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: @PLAK-THEME We do _not_ know that. That's not an equality. See, for instance, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112) about the issue. That being said, you could ask us about whether your series is related to $-\frac1{\sqrt 3}$ the same way that $\sum n$ is related to $-\frac1{12}$.

Comment: @PLAK-THEME $1+2+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$ is not true.

Comment: @PLAK-THEME: No, $1+2+3+...=\infty $.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sum". The Wikipedia article you quote clearly states that taking the usual meaning the series diverges, but that some non-standard approaches can give a a "sum". Which approach are you interested in? Have you tried applying it to your $1/\sqrt{N}$ example?

Comment: Since you keep referencing the wikipedia article for the divergent sum $1+2+3+\cdots,$ which references zeta function regularization and ramanujan summation, I've changed the tag to match that.  That said, I'm a little concerned that you're mistaking these summation methods as equivalent to the standard methods even after several people have tried to point out this flaw in your question to you.

Comment: I guess the question should be rephrased as: provided that $f(s)=\sum_{\substack{n\text{ odd}\\n\text{ composite}}}\frac{1}{n^s}$ defines an analytic function over $\text{Re}(s)>1$, what is the value at $s=\frac{1}{2}$ of the analytic continuation of the previous series?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac1n$, and $$\sum_{n=9}^\infty \frac1n$$ diverges, it follows that the series $$\sum_{n=9}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt N}$$ also diverges.

Comment: Intuitively the sum $\sum_{n=9}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt N}$ diverges as you mentioned, but i'm trying to use the same process as here https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF to prove that this converges to $\frac{-1}{\sqrt(3)}$

Comment: @PLAK-THEME There is no process that can be used to prove that a divergent sum converges. Divergent sums do not converge.

Comment: ok got it thanks