# $1+2+3... =-\frac{1}{12}$ - Question regarding this

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, quadratics, zeta-functions

So, I'm not a big expert in this subject but I know $1+2+3...=-\dfrac{1}{12}$ isn't to do with 'real' maths but it's all to do with the zeta function; however I was watching a maths video and the equation:

$$
\frac{x(x+1)}{2}
$$

... is actually a perfect equation for the series $1+2+3...$ etc. where $x$ represents $n$ in a series and $y$ is the sum of the series up to $n$. So, you can conclude that:

$$
\sum^{n}_{i=1}1+2+3...=\frac{x(x+1)}{2}
$$

However, this is where it gets weird; as you have probably guessed, the roots of the equation is $x=0,-1$  but if I want to find the integral of the roots from $-1$ to $0$ which is under the $x$ axis, I get the following:

$$
\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{x(x+1)}{2}\:dx=-\frac{1}{12}
$$

So, my question is why is this the case; what connection is there between the value of the integral under the $x$ axis that this graph has compared to the summation of the series?

[Link to Desmos graph for more clarity](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d1k8kx4xuc)

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I know that there are really many posts here about this topic, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112) and more than $100$ posts linked to it. More or less you should find everything here on this site already.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2350361/42969 might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Please formulate the sum with more care (expression within the sum i, result is n(n+1)/2). And an area is never negative, the corresponding integral can of course be negative.

Comment: @Peter Yes fair point, edited for more clarity.

Comment: For OP: I believe the downvotes are a knee-jerk reaction for people here who are (understandably) fed up with questions regarding misconceptions about the $-1/12$ thing. That said, I think the question did show effort from OP and was not poorly written (writing $x$ instead of $n$ in $x(x+1)/2$ is just a math mistake the post itself should not be penalized for). So even if I have no interest in discussing this topic, I have upvoted this.

Answer (score -1):

Your result for this integral is just a consequence of a general formula wich gives the value of the zeta function at negative integer. Integrating Faulhabert* (or maybe bernoulli's, i'm not sure) formula between -1 and 0 leads to the formula.

*The formula is the one that gives the n-th partial sum of k-th power of integers in term of polynomials of degree k+1.