# What 1D functions y=f(x) become rotationally symmetric as z=f(x)f(y)?

Tags: improper-integrals, symmetry

I was wondering why $\pi$ shows up in the equation for the area under a Gaussian:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2} ~dx= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
$$
This isn't intuitive to me, as I think of $\pi$ as being intrinsically linked with rotation in 2D or higher, and this function lives in 1D.

Looking at a derivation of this result, it seems that $\pi$ shows up because $e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}$ is rotationally symmetric in 2D. (This lets us calculate the square of the above integral by converting to polar coordinates). So, the area under $e^{-ax^2}$ is related to $\pi$ because its higher dimensional cousin $e^{-ax^2}e^{-ay^2}=e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}$ is rotationally symmetric in 2D.

So, $e^{-ax^2}$ is 2D rotationally symmetric in spirit, even though it lives in 1D. This idea of understanding something about a function by using a higher dimensional symmetry seems interesting. I wonder how many functions have this sort of hidden rotational symmetry. Explicitly, what are the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f_{2D}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ [defined by $f_{2D}(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$] is rotationally symmetric about the z-axis?

It seems that these functions form a group under multiplication (at least as long as they don't take on zero values). The neutral element is $f(x) = 1$ and taking the reciprocal plays the role of the inverse. To see this, note that if some 2D function $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is rotationally symmetric, then so $1/h$. For multiplicative closure, note that if $h_1$ and $h_2$ are 2D rotationally symmetric functions, then so is their product. These 2D properties then induce the desired properties in 1D. Can we find the generators of this group - the basic building blocks that allow us to construct all the other "secretly rotationally symmetric" 1D functions?

**Edit**
Upon reflection, I realized that any rotationally symmetric 2D function $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ has to be of the form $h(x,y) = H(x^2 + y^2)$ for some function $H: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This is because the value of the rotationally symmetric function is totally determined by its distance from the origin. So, for $f$ to be a "secretly rotationally symmetric" 1D function, it is sufficient and necessary that $f_{2D}(x,y) = f(x)f(y) = H(x^2 + y^2)$ for some function $H$.

**Edit 2**
We can also see that $f$ has to be even (if $f$ doesn't take on zero values). We need $f_{2D}(-x,y) = f_{2D}(x,y) \implies f(-x)f(y) = f(x)f(y) \implies f(-x) = f(x)$. So, if $f$ is smooth we can expand it as a Taylor series without any odd powers:
$$
f(x) = f(0) + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \dots + \frac{f^{(2n)}(0)}{(2n)!}x^{2n} + \dots
$$
This means we can write $f(x)$ in terms of a function of $x^2$, say $F(x^2)$. The condition described in Edit 1 then becomes $F(x^2)F(y^2) = H(x^2 + y^2)$. In the special case that $F = H$, we get $F(x^2)F(y^2) = F(x^2 + y^2)$, which is equivalent to $F(x)F(y) = F(x + y)$. [In the case of the Gaussian, we have $F(x^2) = e^{-ax^2}$ or equivalently $F(x) = e^{-ax}$.]

So, under these conditions, it seems sufficient to have $f(x) = F(x^2)$ with $F$ satisfying $F(x)F(y) = F(x + y)$. It is interesting that there appears to be some link between rotational symmetry and this structure preserving condition moving from addition to multiplication. Might there be additional generator functions beyond these?

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro

Comment: And: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112

Comment: Note $F(x^2)F(0)=H(x^2)$, so either $F(0)=0$ so $H=0$ and $F=0$ or $F(x^2)=F(0)G(x^2)$, where $G(x+y)=G(x)G(y)$.  In the second case $G(n/m)^m=G(1)^n$ for $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}, m\neq 0$ so if $G$ is continuous it must have the form $e^{\lambda x}$.  Thus the general solution has the form $f(x)=Ae^{\lambda x^2}$.

Comment: Also you do not need to restrict $f$ to being smooth.  If $f(-x)=f(x)$ then $f=F(x^2)$ for some $F$ by definition, so the Taylor series argument is redundant.  Further you have $f(-x)=f(x)$ as long as $f\neq0$ - you do not need to restrict $f$ to being a non-zero function.  So this really is all solutions.

Comment: Before I saw your superior solution, I was going to suggest $$\frac d {d\theta}f(r\cos(\theta))f(r\sin(\theta))=0$$ which simplifies to $$\frac {f'(x)}{xf(x)}=c$$ which has general solution $f(x)=Ae^{c/2x^2}$.

Comment: So the group you mentioned is $C_2 \times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is regarded as a group with respect to addition.  I am not posting this as an answer as you did almost all the work.