# P-adic numbers and infinity? Does infinity as a limit exist for p-adics?

Tags: infinity, p-adic-number-theory

I don't think I understand how p-adic numbers relate to the usual concept of infinity. The wiki page and various sources on the internet did not help.

Let's see for example the 10-adic counterparts to the real numbers (10 is not prime, but it is more convenient here for demonstration purposes):

$$
0 \rightarrow 0 \\
1 \rightarrow 1 \\
2 \rightarrow 2 \\
$$

Anyway, for any positive whole number we have the usual representation. On the other hand:

$$
-1 \rightarrow ...9999 \\
-2 \rightarrow ...9998 \\
-3 \rightarrow ...9997 \\
$$

But if $...9999$ is not equivalent to $+ \infty$ then where is the infinity? Is zero the infinity?

$$
-1+1=0 \rightarrow ...0000=0 \\
$$

Do negative and positive infinities 'meet in the middle' between $0$ and $-1$?

It also seems that many infinite series divergent in the field of reals, converge in the field of p-adic numbers. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141971/269624) question is about the divergent series, but I am more interested in the general concept of infinity for p-adics.

For now it seems to me that p-adics incorporate everything in the same form - whole numbers, rational and irrational numbers, negative numbers and even infinity.

Comment: Infinity, as commonly used in limits, can't be a p-adic number because the p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ form a field, and field axioms are incompatible with the property $\infty + a = \infty$. But as with any other field, you can define its projective line, $\mathbb{Q}_p \mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{Q}_p \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: "I don't think I understand how p-adic numbers relate to the usual concept of infinity". I don't think I understand what you mean by "the usual concept of infinity". Consequently, this question makes no sense to me.