Sum of all Fibonacci Numbers equals $-1$?
Context: I was pondering aimlessly when I thought of this, and I don't have any reason to say why this is wrong, other than I know it is wrong
My thoughts go like this: (Before we start, By Fibonacci, I mean the sequence $a_{n}$ where $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$, given $a_{0} = a_{1} = 1$)
Let $S$ be the sum of all Fibonacci terms, thus
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \tag1$$
So,
$$\begin{align}
S + S &= a_0 + (a_0 + a_1) + (a_1 + a_2) + (a_2 + a_3) + \ldots \tag2\\[4pt]
\implies\quad 2S &= a_0 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + \ldots \tag3\\[4pt]
&= a_0 + S - a_0 - a_1 \tag4\\[4pt]
\implies\quad S &= -a_1 = -1 \tag5
\end{align}$$
Problem: Why is this wrong? Although it sounds simple, I brainstormed for an hour but landed on no solid reason. Because of how I subtracted $S$ from $2S$? Or adding $S + S$ because they don't overlap perfectly as I leave a term of the first sum behind? Even so, I don't know why, if the inaccuracy is one of the above two listed, it is wrong.
Help is really, really appreciated

It is wrong because the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ does not exist.

There are several similar questions, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37327/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441723/42969.

It is wrong because it assumes an infinite sum results in a finite value.

If you want another pseudo-proof of the result, note that the generating function $F(z)=\sum a_nz^n=\frac 1{1-(z+z^2)}$ satisfies $F(1)=-1$.  Of course, once you start attaching values to divergent series, all sorts of things can crop up.

This approach, with some modifications,  will work to find a closed formula for $F(z)=\sum_n f_nz^n,$ the so-called "generating function" of the Fiibonacci sequence, and it does turn out the analytics extension of $F$ has $F(1)=1.$

@lulu The numerator of $F$ is $z,$ not $1$, at least for the usual case where $a_0=0.$

@ThomasAndrews  Right.  I started at $1$, for whatever reason.  Doesn't change the result, of course, $F(1)=-1$

@Thomas Andrews (and Lulu) : I think one of you should transform your comment(s) into an answer because it is very instructive and could be referred to if similar questions are asked in the future. Besides, this series must be convergent to $-1$ in some p-adic "worlds" but this is another point.

Many false proofs take the form of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ax_k = a \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$. Distributivity does not work for divergent series.

This question shouldn't be downvoted : the asker says right in the beginning that he/she is conscious the calculations are wrong, has worked and ask us to pinpoint where it is wrong and the explanation through the use/abuse of a generating function (Thomas Andrews and Lulu) is especially interesting.

Same question here with an answer of mine giving an opening towards a p-adic interpretation.

@JeanMarie I was pretty sure this has been asked many different times, in many variants, starting with the many people asking about $$1+2+3+\cdots=-\frac1{12},$$ after a popular math YouTube video,presented that as simply true.

There is no $p$-adic interpretation for,any $p$ for this sequence, since the terms in the closed formula are of the form $c(a^n-b^n),$ where $ab=-1.$  @JeanMarie

For what it's worth, I have posted a community solution reflecting the (standard) analytic continuation approach we sketched in the comments.  Nothing unusual or original in what I wrote, but maybe it's useful to summarize it here.

@Thomas Andrews I hadn't thought along these lines. Thank you very much !

Upvote here. Why is this downvoted? The author presented the question clearly and knew that the answer was wrong. This seems like an educational opportunity destroyed by the downvotes.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
You have to be very careful in attaching values to divergent series.  Standard arithmetic manipulation leads to "paradoxical" results.  For instance, if $S=\sum (-1)^n=1-1+1-1+\cdots$ then plausible arithmetic would tell us that $$S=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots=0$$
or $$S=1-(1-1)-(1-1)+\cdots =1 $$
or $$-S=-1+1-1+\cdots =-1+S\implies S=\frac 12$$
and so on.
That said, there are various methods of working with divergent series systematically and these sometimes lead to interesting results.
Analytic continuation is a standard method.  If you have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ you can look at the power series $F(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ and try to extend it analytically.  If the function has an analytic continuation that covers $z=1$, it might be tempting to define the value of the divergent series to be $F(1)$ or something like that.
For instance, you might note that $$G(z)=\sum z^n=1+z+z^2+\cdots =\frac 1{1-z}$$ when $|z|<1$, but of course that function makes sense for all $z\neq 1$.  Taking $z=-1$ gives the series $S$ I mentioned earlier and, following this approach, we might define $S=G(-1)=\frac 12$.  And perhaps you feel that makes sense, but $G(2)=-1$ and are you happy with $1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots =-1$?  Of course, letting $T=1+2+2^2+\cdots$, ordinary arithmetic suggests that $2T=T-1$ which, again, implies $T=-1$, so in this sense it is consistent.
In your case, we consider $f_n$, the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, and define $$F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_nz^n=0+z+z^2+2z^3+\cdots$$
As an exercise, you can try to prove that this converges for $z$ in some non-trivial neighborhood of $z=0$ (Hint: use the Binet formula).
The method you discussed makes sense here (at least inside the region of convergence) and we us $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ to deduce that $$F(z)=0+z+zF(z)+z^2F(z)$$ which implies that $$F(z)=\frac z{1-z-z^2}$$
Note:  This differs from what I wrote in the comments in that the numerator is $z$ instead of $1$.  That's because this time I started the sequence with $f_0=0$ instead of $f_0=1$ just to bring it in line with more standard notation. This difference was (correctly) pointed out by @ThomasAndrews in the comments and I have changed my function to align with his suggestion.
Now, that function extends analytically to the entire plane, save for the roots of the quadratic denominator.
It's easy to see that $F(1)=-1$ in line with your result.
To stress.  None of this should be taken as a sum of the series in any standard sense.  The series diverges, it does not converge to any value.  But I think the analytic continuation method gives a coherent way to interpret the result.

Thank you for this answer.
